# Is it possible to create multiple facebook SDK instances on a single page without conflict?

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm working on an application that can be embedded in other pages using an iFrame that requires facebook permissions. The problem is we're running into issues when trying to use the facebook SDK to login from inside an iFrame on iOS (the login window never appears). We're running code on the parent page that places the iFrame, so my question is, can I place our SDK on the parent page without conflicting with any existing Facebook SDKs on that page?

Comment: No, you can’t. The JS SDK can only be embedded and initialized once.

Comment: @CBroe That's the impression I got after trying to get it working. If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Sure. Added a few additional thoughts for possible alternatives to explore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I place our SDK on the parent page without conflicting with any existing Facebook SDKs on that page?

No, you can’t. The JS SDK can only be embedded and initialized once.

> The problem is we're running into issues when trying to use the facebook SDK to login from inside an iFrame on iOS (the login window never appears)

The whole JS SDK popup login flow is not the most suitable for mobile in many cases.

You might have better luck implementing the manual login flow, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow

If you open that in a new window, you’d have to find a way to close it again, and have the iframe notified that successful login has happend. (Perhaps postMessage before closing the login window.)

Another possible option would be to redirect in the top window (instead of opening a new window/popup), and then after login back to the 3rd-party site, that loads your iframe again. (But not all people using your plugin on their page might like that.)